# Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [httprequest] methods

Tags: apex

Trying to create an Apex Class or Do a callout in Open execute anonymous window from my Dev Org, all the HTTP Request Methods are returning Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [httprequest].setXXX(String)

For Ex:

```
public class AuthCallout {

   public void basicAuthCallout(){
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
     req.setEndpoint('http://www.yahoo.com');
     req.setMethod('GET');

     // Specify the required user name and password to access the endpoint
     // As well as the header and header information

     String username = 'myname';
     String password = 'mypwd';

     Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
     String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
     EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
     req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

     // Create a new http object to send the request object
     // A response object is generated as a result of the request  

     Http http = new Http();
     HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
     System.debug(res.getBody());
   }
}
```

from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm fails to save as an apex class with the Error message:

> Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   [httprequest].setEndpoint(String)

Comment: Have you inadvertently created your own class called `HttpRequest`? Try just doing an anonymous `HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();System.debug(req);`

Comment: Ha, I might have by accident - FAIL

Comment: Yup, found an empty http request class in my devorg from months ago

Comment: It happens :) You might be able to work around it by prefixing with the namespace, but it would be safer to just get rid of the conflicting class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of error usually occurs if you create an Apex class with the same name as the System class.

Look for an Apex class called `HttpRequest` and either delete it or rename it.

Comment: deleted it as soon as I found it, some empty class hanging there that was probably created by mistake months ago

Comment: That Past Self person has a lot to answer for. Mine is always screwing me up.